# GitLab Pipeline Throws Invalid Provider Configuration Error on Terraform Configuration

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, hashicorp-vault, gitlab-pipelines, terraform-provider

I have some Terraform configuration which has up until now run successfully without any issues locally and without me explicitly inserting any provider block.

I transferred this very same set of configuration to a GitLab pipeline with 4 pipeline stages of Validate, Plan, Apply and Destroy declared in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and suddenly the 'terraform plan' command fails at the Plan stage with the below "Invalid provider configuration" error.

[image]

This is all despite the fact that the 'terraform validate' command runs successfully at the initial pipeline stage - Validate.

Any idea why my configuration will suddenly be throwing this error in my GitLab pipeline when it's been perfectly fine when run locally?

Comment: Did you install the plugins? What version of terraform are you using locally and what version of terraform are you using in GitLab CI?

Comment: Do you have `provider "vault"` and `provider "azuread"` blocks in your root module to specify the required settings for these two providers?

Comment: `terraform validate` doesn't configure providers, because it's intended for use in contexts where you might not have provider credentials available, such as CI runs in a VCS. `terraform plan` is a more thorough validation which considers external inputs such as available credentials, input variables, etc, and so it will often catch things that `terraform validate` cannot.

Comment: Appreciate the good feedback svtech and @Martin Atkins. In answer to your respective questions, no I don't install any plugins and on the subject of version of terraform used locally as against that in my GitLab CI, I doubt that could be the cause, as other terraform pipelines (aside this specific one) run successfully on our GitLab CI server. Martin Atkins makes a good point regarding the two provider blocks - my answer to that is no, I don't have them in my root module and didn't include them as I didn't require them locally. I will however insert them in the GitLab instance and retry.

Comment: Probably locally you already have som environments variables setted like `VAULT_ADDR` for the vault provider. My point is that the machine is not the same, so probably something is missing on GitLab runner that is automatically found in your local machine.